# can i run an automation only when a data extension have data or records?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, automation

I have an automation that runs periodically and email campaign begins with the data in a data extension.

In last step of my automation, i cam deleting the records in the data extension so that processed records do not come back again in next cycle of the automation.

But sometimes there is a situation in which there is no new data in the data extension to process but automation still triggers because it is a scheduled automation. Hence, I get error that data extract failed and automation failed.

Is there any way to ONLY run the automation when there are 1 or more records in a data extension. If data extension is blank then skip the automaton.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a new [Verification Activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/june_2017_release/journey_builder/) in Automation Studio. You can set this to verify if there are no subscribers in DE then stop the automation. This will prevent the error.

> **New Verification Activity**
>
> Add the new Verification activity to automation workflows to help
>   increase confidence in running journeys and prevent unintended
>   outcomes that may not otherwise result in an error. For example, a
>   query activity resulting in 0 subscribers instead of the expected
>   50,000 can require verification.
>
> Find the Verification activity in the Activities list when editing an
>   automation’s workflow. You can include multiple Verification
>   activities in a single step, but Verification activities may not exist
>   in steps with other activity types. When run, the activity checks the
>   current record count of a specified data extension. If the record
>   count falls outside a defined range, the activity sends an email
>   notification, stops the automation, or both.